# Laravel: SQL Error after composer update when there is a db query in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I added one line of code `View::share('categories', \App\Models\Category::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get());` to my AppServiceProvider.php so that it looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Bootstrap
        Paginator::useBootstrap();

        // Line of Code
        View::share('categories', \App\Models\Category::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get());
    }
}
```

My problem:
When running `composer update` following error gets displayed:

```
@php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from `categories` order by `sortorder` asc)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()

  2   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

When I disable the additional line of code in my AppServiceProvider.php everything during composer update is working without any errors. But when the additional line of code is used, then this error is thrown. What's causing this issue? Why is this `view::share()` causing this problem when running `composer update`?

My .env file looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

The website itself is working without any errors (database content is fetched correctly). This error occurs only when `composer update` is executed.

When I change `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1` the command `composer update` works without any errors. However, then, the website is not working anymore because the database is hosted on the docker container "mysql" and not hosted in the same container as laravel. Why is `composer update` successfull when passing a wrong/false parameter to it?

This is the docker file:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
            - phpmyadmin
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        networks:
            - sail
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not the `view::share`, it's the `\App\Models\Category::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get()`, which is trying to access your database. You apparently don't have the database connection variables set correctly in database.php or your .env file.

Comment: You must share your docker, you are not sharing a network with that MySQL container, are they in the same docker-compose?